# Can Mathematica show me a fraction with a repeating decimal notation?

Tags: formatting

The value of `3/817` when expressed using the `N[3/817, 100]` shows me data without helping me see the repeating patterns:

After I mess around with the results in Notepad, I can reformat it in notepad so I see the repeating decimals, but what I would really like to see is a line over the repeating group of digits, like this:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200617/how-can-i-make-a-working-repeating-decimal-representation-of-a-rational-number

Comment: I didn't even think of Mathematica being covered on the original StackOverflow site.

Comment: Strongly related thread on Wolfram Community: "[Output repeating decimal numbers with an overline?](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1020821)"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
repeatingForm[x_Rational] := Module[
   {realDigits, integerPart, fractionalPart, start, repeat, exp},
   integerPart = IntegerPart[x];
   fractionalPart = FractionalPart[x];
   realDigits = RealDigits[fractionalPart];
   Which[
    MatchQ[realDigits, {{__Integer, {__Integer}}, _Integer}],
    start = Most[First[realDigits]];
    repeat = Last[First[realDigits]],
    MatchQ[realDigits, {{{__Integer}}, _Integer}],
    start = {};
    repeat = Last[First[realDigits]],
    MatchQ[realDigits, {{__Integer}, _Integer}],
    start = First[realDigits];
    repeat = {}
    ];
   exp = Last[realDigits];
   If[exp < 0,
    start = Join[Table[0, {-exp}], start]];
   If[Length[repeat] > 0,
    Row[Flatten[{N[integerPart], start, OverBar[Row[repeat]]}]],
    Row[Flatten[{N[integerPart], start}]]
    ]
   ];
```

Let's try it on Vitaliy's original set of data points.  (I guess he deleted this portion.)

```
data = {98464/3, 2209604/53, 1654407/32, 4695213/44, 2608035/32, 
  1060220/31, 1254299/54, 3180989/37, 1120269/83, 6084320/73};
repeatingForm /@ data // Column
```

[image]

Comment: I can tell you why: Because `RealDigits` needs to be tested. In something like `RealDigits[1/2]` one inner `List` missing and when I see this right, this case is not tested. +1 btw.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, Mark, I fixed the bug.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Cool! This was definitely a little trickier than I thought it would be when I jumped in!

Comment: Yes, indeed, ;) +1 btw

Comment: Thanks. This is really good info for someone just learning how to write functions in mathematica.

Comment: This one works with my original example (3/817) which is a very long repeating digit sequence indeed, and so I consider the technique more robust than the others, and preferable to requiring an internet connection (wolfram alpha).

Comment: Your function can be easily generalized to print in arbitrary base $b\le36$: just add a second argument to `RealDigits`.

Comment: Also, it appears unevaluated for integers, although it would work normally for them. To fix this, you can change `x_Rational` to `x_?(Head@# == Rational || IntegerQ[#] &)`.

Answer (score 25):

**--- final function ---**

I recommend reading article [**Repeating Decimal**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatingDecimal.html). Function `RealDigits` gives you complete information:

```
RealDigits[237/14]
```

> {{1, 6, 9, {2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4}}, 2}

as seen from

```
N[237/14, 30]
```

[image]

Write a function that shows an overbar and period:

```
RepeatingDecimal[x_Rational] := With[{tv = RealDigits[x]},
  Subscript[Row[Insert[Cases[tv[[1]], _Integer]~Join~
      (OverBar /@ Flatten[Cases[tv[[1]], _List]]), ".", tv[[-1]] + 1]]
   , Length[tv[[1, -1]]]]]
```

Test it out:

```
dat = DeleteCases[(RandomInteger[{1, 10^7}, 5]/RandomInteger[{10, 50}, 5]), _Integer]
```

[image]

```
Grid[{RepeatingDecimal[#], N[#, 20]} & /@ dat, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

**--- via internet connection ---**

You can use built-in Wolfram Alpha integration:

```
RepDec[x_Rational] := 
  WolframAlpha[ToString[InputForm[x]], {{"RepeatingDecimal", 1}, "Content"}]
```

Test this out:

```
RepDec[4692085/38]
```

[image]

Comment: Your function does not work correctly for `1/2` and e.g. `1060220/31`.

Comment: @halirutan I fixed the bug, thanks. Wolfram Alpha function will work only with "good" numbers for obvious reasons - other numbers do not have corresponding pod.

Comment: Wow!  This is impressive.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Finally a very nice answer +1.

Comment: The output looks wonky for my original fraction, which is a very long series of repeating digits.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Could you explain what you meant, in your comment, by "Wolfram Alpha function will only work with 'good' numbers"?

Comment: Try these: `RepeatingDecimal[4/7] + RepeatingDecimal[3/7]` and
`RepeatingDecimal[4/7] 2 `.  Then you may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200617/how-can-i-make-a-working-repeating-decimal-representation-of-a-rational-number

Comment: @DavidCarraher If a number is not repeating decimal, Alpha server will not produce corresponding pod.

Comment: @DavidCarraher This is just a formatting function - it does not do the algebra. There are some other issues that I am currently working on though.

Comment: Yes, that was my point.

Comment: +1 I like the succinctness of `tv[[-1]] + 1`.

Comment: Your function gives strange results for `1234/9999*10^-4`: instead of $0.0000\overline{1234}_4$ it says $\overline{12}.\overline{34}_4$.

Answer (score 10):

This code will automatically write rationals as repeating (or finite) decimals. The decimals have a tooltip that show which rational they represent and are automatically truncated for long repeating sections. The decimal is not editable, so that it can't be broken when copying (this can probably be improved upon). To edit the number, select it and [convert to inputform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/InputForm.html).

```
Unprotect[Rational];
Rational /: MakeBoxes[r : Rational[_Integer, _Integer], _] := 
 With[{trunc = 45, d = RealDigits[FractionalPart[r]]},
  With[{boxes = ToBoxes[Style[Tooltip[
        Row[Flatten@{IntegerPart[r], ".", ConstantArray[0, -d[[2]]],
           If[Head[d[[1, -1]]] === List, {Most@First@d, OverBar[                  
              Row[If[Length[#] > trunc, Join[#[[1 ;; trunc]], 
                {"\[LeftSkeleton]", Length@# - trunc, "\[RightSkeleton]"}], #]]&@d[[1, -1]]]}, 
              First@d]}],
        Row[{Numerator[r], " /", Denominator[r]}]], 
       Selectable -> False, ShowStringCharacters -> False]
      ]},
   InterpretationBox[boxes, r]
    ]]
Protect[Rational];
```

e.g.,

[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]

Here's examples of truncating long repeating decimals
[image: Example3]
Note that for complicated rational numbers, this code to format them as repeating decimals can take some time, simply due to calculating and displaying the [RealDigits](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealDigits.html).

Comment: +1 for making the formatted output usable as input.

Comment: This gets to be a better approach the longer the output sequences get.

Comment: Is there another command I could use to toggle Rational back to its default behaviour if I found I wanted to toggle it?

Comment: @WarrenP: It's not a toggle, but you can restore the original behaviour: `Unprotect[Rational];Clear[Rational];Protect[Rational];`

Comment: I've also increased `trunc` to 45, so that it works on your original set of examples.