# A question regarding 1 divided 243

Tags: number-theory

Here is a problem due to Feynman. If you take 1 divided by 243 you get 0.004115226337 .... It goes a little cockeyed after 559 when you're carrying out the decimal expansion, but it soon straightens itself out and repreats itself nicely. Now I want to see how many times it repeats itself. Does it do this indefinitely, or does it stop after certain number of repititions? Can you write a simple *Mathematica* program to verify one conjecture or the other?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by "how many times it repeats itself"? 1/243 is a fraction whose denominator does not contain any power of 2 or 5, so its decimal expansion is indeed periodic and infinite.

Comment: Related: [Can Mathematica show me a fraction with a repeating decimal notation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15818)

Comment: Since none of the answers mention this and I am not interested in further elaboration: `Length[RealDigits[1/243][[1, 1]]] == MultiplicativeOrder[10, 243]`

Answer (score 18):

```
RealDigits[1/243] 
(*
 {{{4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3, 7, 4, 4, 8, 5, 5, 9, 6, 7, 0, 7, 8, 1, 8, 9, 3, 0, 0}}, -2}
*)
```

Comment: Vote held until you explain the significance of this for those to whom it is not apparent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the necessary explanation is already written in the `RealDigits[]` docs. Feel free to retain your vote.

Answer (score 11):

```
NumberForm[N[1/243,135],DigitBlock->27]
```

> 0.004115226337448559670781893 004115226337448559670781893 004115226337448559670781893 004115226337448559670781893 004115226337448559670781893 00

let x = 0.004115226337448559670781893... then for it to repeat forever would require that

```
eqn = (10^27  -1) x == 4115226337448559670781893;

Solve[eqn, x]
```

> {{x->1/243}}

Hence it repeats forever.

Answer (score 6):

Since belisarius specifically refused to expound on his answer, which arguably would make my editing it for such purpose tantamount to vandalism, I shall post my own.

Regarding [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealDigits.html):

> For integers and rational numbers with terminating digit expansions, RealDigits[x] returns an ordinary list of digits. For rational numbers with non-terminating digit expansions it yields a list of the form {a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,{b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>,...}} representing the digit sequence consisting of the a<sub>i</sub> followed by infinite cyclic repetitions of the b<sub>i</sub>.  »

Therefore we can use `RealDigits` to find the non-terminating cyclic digits of a fraction.  The output syntax is of the form `{{___, r : {__}}, _}` where `r` is the list of repeating digits.  The digits are easily extracted using that pattern, or more tersely [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Level.html):

```
RealDigits[1/243] ~Level~ {3}
```

> ```
> {4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3, 7, 4, 4, 8, 5, 5, 9, 6, 7, 0, 7, 8, 1, 8, 9, 3, 0, 0}
> ```

For comparison a number with a terminating decimal expansion:

```
RealDigits[1/4] ~Level~ {3}
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: referring to Belisarius' answer: What does the last `-2` stand for?

Comment: @eldo The position of the decimal point, which here is two to the left of the first listed digit, i.e. `.004115226...`

Comment: I don't want to steal your time: But why doesn't return `ReturnDigits` {0,0,4,...3} ? Wouldn't that be clearer ?

Comment: @eldo In this particular case I agree that would seem to be cleaner, but by convention `RealDigits` strips leading zeros from its representation.  (That's probably not the best way to state that.)

Comment: Just to clarify: I refused to edit my answer because I think it isn't necessary, but I would NEVER call you a [vandal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandals), no matter how you edit my posts.

Comment: @belisarius Alright.  Next time I shall add any explanatory content I feel will help the noobs. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In case it wasn't clear enough. _I_ know the vandals quite well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandals#The_turbulent_end :)

Comment: @belisarius Oh; looks like subtlety, history, and humor were all lost on me. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know about history, but I'm sure subtlety  and humor are healthy and kicking right in front of your computer. Cheers!

Comment: @eldo, here's a good example that shows why zeros are stripped: `RealDigits[1/(243*10^1000000)]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also call `WolframAlpha["1/243"]`.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case (could be easily extended):

```
Count[#, Max@#] &[ StringLength /@ Rest@StringSplit[ToString@N[1/243, 10^6], "00"]]

37037
```

With `10^6` digits after the decimal point there are `37037` repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

When you examine the repetitions over a larger scale, another interesting repetition shows up.

using the same code as eldo:

```
Count[#, Max@#] &[ StringLength /@ Rest@StringSplit[ToString@N[1/243, 10^2], "00"]]
```

with `10^2` digits all the way to `10^9` showing repetitions of:

> 3
>
> 37
>
> 370
>
> 3703
>
> 37037
>
> 370370
>
> 3703703
>
> 37037037