# How to force Mathematica to do infinite-precision calculations?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, number-representation, arbitrary-precision

Consider the following calculation:

```
1234*5678*90.12
```

The result is:

```
6.31439*10^8
```

However, I want to get a precise result. Of course, I can always write for example:

```
NumberForm[1234*5678*90.12, 20]
```

But that gives me

```
6.314394782399999*10^8
```

which is clearly not correct. Another possible solution is to force 90.12 to have a certain precision, e.g.:

```
1234*5678*90.12`20
```

which gives

```
6.3143947824000000000*10^8
```

but that's not really what I want either, since there's always the possibility (with more complicated calculations) that maybe there's a secret non-zero digit hiding somewhere more than 20 digits after the decimal and thus will be missed with only 20 digits of precision.

The only way I found to make Mathematica actually do an **infinite precision** calculation is to write

```
1234*5678*9012/100
```

but that gives me

```
15785986956/25
```

which isn't what I want either, since I want to get a decimal representation. Again, I could write something like

```
N[1234*5678*9012/100, 20]
```

which gives

```
6.3143947824000000000*10^8
```

but that still only has 20 digits of precision, not infinite precision.

So my question is: how can I force Mathematica to do an **infinite-precision** calculation - I stress again, not to any specific finite precision (e.g. 20), but infinite precision - and give me the precise result **up to the last non-zero digit after the decimal point**?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Even if you confine yourself to rationals, only a rare subset (those whose minimal denominator contains no prime factors other than 2 and 5) can be expressed as an exact decimal.

Comment: Given that approximate numbers are represented in binary, this might be a challenge. For example the decimal .12 does not have a finite binary representation. So at some point in such computations, rounding will have to be done.

Comment: **Infinite precision** requires conversion to exact numbers rather using inexact numbers. Either `1234*5678*SetPrecision[90.12, Infinity]` or `1234*5678*Rationalize[90.12, 0]`. After calculating with exact numbers, use `N[#, prec]&` to display with `prec` digits of precision. Of course, exact calculations are slower than inexact calculations.

Comment: You can change the output formatting of an expression, but you cannot really change the internal representation. (Not without writing a library package to support your new creation, especially about something so fundamental to the system as numbers.) `15785986956/25` is the only infinite precision representation, AFAIK, but you can display it in all sorts of ways.  See for instance, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15818/can-mathematica-show-me-a-fraction-with-a-repeating-decimal-notation

Comment: @JohnDoty: it's just something I run into often when doing calculations. I'm never sure if the number I got is precise to the last decimal digit. I want to do precise calculations, so I actually **don't** want to represent the numbers as floating point, I want the calculation to be done solely using Mathematica's infinite-precision capabilities with no floating-point representations involved.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Same as my previous comment. I don't want floating-point, I want infinite precision, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @BobHanlon: I tried `1234*5678*SetPrecision[90.12, Infinity]` and that actually gives me `1388550097123381133255/2199023255552` which is **not** the correct answer! I'm not sure what's going on, but my guess is that maybe it first represents 90.12 in machine precision and then approximates that in infinite precision, which is not what I want.

Comment: I still don't understand. What do you want to see for `7/257`?

Comment: @JohnDoty: For numbers with repeating decimals I guess this wouldn't make sense. But surely there must be some way to calculate `1234*5678*90.12` and display all its decimal digits (of which there is a finite number) without having to specify a particular precision?

Comment: No, you do not want infinite precision. You exculed that when you ruled out using `1234*5678*9012/100`. What you apparently want is finite precision in decimal rather than binary arithmetic. As I stated, this will be difficult to achieve.

Comment: No no, I do in fact want infinite precision. Yes, I know that Mathematica interprets `90.12` as machine precision automatically, so to be more precise, I want to display `1234*5678*9012/100` as a decimal without having to specify a precision (which might be too small and thus not show all the digits). Actually, I think the answer linked to by @MichaelE2 is what I'm looking for: `RealDigits[1234*5678*9012/100]` displays all the digits (including even for repeating decimals if I understand correctly?) without having to specify a precision.

Comment: The `exact` value of machine precision number `90.12` is ambiguous. `Rationalize[90.12, 0]` gives the exact value of the decimal representation; whereas, `SetPrecision[90.12, Infinity]` gives the exact value of the stored binary number. From the docs "When SetPrecision is used to increase the precision of a number, the number is padded with zeros. The zeros are taken to be in base 2."  You select which one you use to resolve the ambiguity based on your intent. Their inexact representations are identical, i.e., `N[Rationalize[90.12, 0]] === N[SetPrecision[90.12, Infinity]]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Okay. If you start with an exact rational value, and use `RealDigits`, then I think you will get what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Mathematica* will perform exact arithmetic only so long as all quantities are expressed as [exact numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#9834).  `90.12` is an inexact number with machine precision (i.e. floating point).  Corresponding exact representations include `9012/1000` or `9012*^-2`.

For numbers with a finite decimal representation, we can use [RealDigits](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html) to see all the digits along with a count of how many appear before the decimal point:

```
RealDigits[1234*5678*9012/100]
```

[image: decimal representation]

`RealDigits` will also give us a finite representation for repeating decimals with the repeated sequence appearing in a sublist:

```
RealDigits[Prime[10000]/7]
```

[image: decimal representation]

For transcendental numbers we are out of luck for an exact decimal representation.  We must specify how many digits we wish to see:

```
RealDigits[Pi]
```

[image: error]

```
RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10^6]
```

[image: decimal representation]

Comment: This indeed works! But it's cumbersome to use. I wish there was a built-in Mathematica function that actually writes down the full number in decimal representation and marks repeated decimals if applicable, such as the ones suggested [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15818/can-mathematica-show-me-a-fraction-with-a-repeating-decimal-notation). For my needs I will probably write my own function that does something similar, but it would have been nice if it was built in. Wolfram, if you're reading this, please consider adding such a function!

Comment: @Wolf On basis of recent Wolfram livestreams I'm under an impression of such forms being planned for Wolfram Language, but they're definitely not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to get a decimal representation" is not compatible with infinite precision because some rational numbers like 1/3 have infinite decimal representation that does not fit into a computer.

You pointed out a solution: use fractions.

Equivalently you could represent exactly a rational number using its period, like

1/3 == 0.Repeated[3]

1344/19 == 70.Repeated[736842105263157894]

The successive digits can be obtained by Euclidean division, for example:

```
In[1066]:= Last /@ 
 Rest@NestList[{Mod[#[[1]], #[[2]]] 10, #[[2]], 
     Quotient[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, {1344, 19}, 30]

Out[1066]= {70, 7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4, \
7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6}
```

The digits before the decimal point are just the first `Quotient[1344, 19]`.

`FindRepeat` finds the period.

```
In[1071]:= 
Rest[Last /@ 
   Rest@NestList[{Mod[#[[1]], #[[2]]] 10, #[[2]], 
       Quotient[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, {1344, 19}, 30]] // FindRepeat

Out[1071]= {7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4}
```

The cycle completes when mod and quotient come back to same previous values, which necessarily occurs before 19*10 steps.  30 was enough in the example.

The number of digits needed for this periodic representation should be about the same order of magnitude for large numbers as the number or digits in the reduced fraction.

The periodic representation is definitely better if you need to compare the numbers quickly.

Finally this seems to work:

```
In[1095]:= Clear@periodic; 
periodic[x_Rational] := {IntegerPart@x, 
  Rest[Last /@ 
     Rest@NestList[{Mod[#[[1]], #[[2]]] 10, #[[2]], 
         Quotient[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, NumeratorDenominator@x, 
       10 Denominator@x + 1]] // FindRepeat}

In[1096]:= periodic[1344/19]

Out[1096]= {70, {7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4}}

In[1098]:= N[1344/19, 30]

Out[1098]= 70.7368421052631578947368421053

In[1097]:= periodic[1/7]

Out[1097]= {0, {1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}}
```

Then you could workout a pretty format with `ToString`, `StringJoin`...

I just realize that `RealDigits` does it, never mind, do it yourself is instructive.

**Further developments**

I had the idea to express the output of `RealDigits[1/7]` like `{0,Repeated[142857]}`.  Of course this does not evaluate to anything but the pattern gives a sense that it could be used for algebra.

To avoid confusion, I can use easily `repeated` instead of `Repeated`.

Periodic algebra examples:  `{1,repeated[12]}+{2,repeated[23]}` would evaluate to `{3,repeated[34]}`, `{1,repeated[12]}*1000` would evaluate to `{1000,repeated[12]}` but it is more difficult to evaluate directly `{1,repeated[12]}+{2,repeated[234]}` or `{1,repeated[12]}*{2,repeated[23]}`.

Again, to avoid confusion, I should not use directly `+` and `*` but some `periodicPlus` and `periodicTimes` but surely you understand better what I mean with `+` and `*`.

Also I have used `1000` instead of `{1000,Repeated[0]}`, that is type conversion.

The periodic algebra is isomorphic to the rational algebra and the `RealDigits` has a simple inverse function so it is quite easy to solve periodic algebra by isomorphism.

Is the periodic representation more or less informative than the rational representation?  It is definitely more informative with respect to order. How does the period length evolve when numbers are combined?

Comment: I don't understand how you're using the `Repeated` function. For example, `0. Repeated[3]` has value shown as `0.`, as does `0. Repeated[3]/(NumberForm[#, 20] &)`.

Comment: I am just trying to imagine an output format.

Comment: @Pierre the fact is, [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) is a built in with a totally different meaning, hence the confusion, so it would be best to use something else in your mocked-up representation.

Comment: Yes and the remark leads to the algebra of this periodic representation, I added to the answer for this.