# Express rational and infinite expressions in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, arithmetic

I have several doubts about notation. I would appreciate any clarifications.

**a)** I can express, for example, a periodic or semi-periodic number without writing it in its rational form. Can such notation be recognized by Mathematica?

*Examples:*

$$a= 0. \bar{8},
b= 1.34\bar{5}$$

**b)** If I do the a/b operation with the numbers above, how do I force Mathematica to write the result in a non-decimal rational form?

**c)** How do I solve the following equations involving nested radicals?

$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}=12$$
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-...}}}}=15$$

edit
It seems that I did not express myself very well. If I have any rational decimal as a result, how can I get MMA to express it to me in the form a/b?
**Apologies for putting more than one question, I thought they were part of the same**

Comment: For your first query about repeating decimals: see [15818](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15818/can-mathematica-show-me-a-fraction-with-a-repeating-decimal-notation)

Comment: For c) take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87359/limit-of-nested-radical-sqrt1-sqrt222-sqrt333.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple distinct questions in one post. It's not obvious how question (c) is related to the former 2 questions.

Comment: For $a$, we have `FromDigits[{{0, {8}}, 1}]` and for $b$ `FromDigits[{{1, 3, 4, {5}}, 1}]`. You can look up the docs for the input syntax of `FromDigits`/`RealDigits`.

Comment: For **c)**, if $a_n\rightarrow y$, then `Solve[{y == Sqrt[x + y], y == 12}, {y, x}]` and
`Solve[{y == Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x - y]], y == 15}, {y, x}]` can be used to solve for `x`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = ResourceFunction["RepeatingDecimalToRational"][0.8, 1]

(* 8/9 *)

a // N[#, 20] &

(* 0.88888888888888888889 *)

b = ResourceFunction["RepeatingDecimalToRational"][1.345, 1]

(* 1211/900 *)

b // N[#, 20] &

(* 1.3455555555555555556 *)
```

**EDIT:** If you do not wish to use `ResourceFunction["RepeatingDecimalToRational"]`,  [`RootApproximant`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant.html) or [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) will often give the desired result depending on the precision involved.

```
bd = 1211/900.

(* 1.34556 *)

#@bd & /@ {RootApproximant, Rationalize}

(* {1211/900, 1211/900} *)
```

However,

```
bd2 = 1211/900.0`9

(* 1.34555556 *)

#@bd2 & /@ {RootApproximant, Rationalize, Rationalize[#, 0] &}

(* {Root[-2 + #^3 - 3 #^5 - #^6 + #^7 + #^8& , 2, 0], 1.34555556, 1211/900} *)
```

**END EDIT**

Equate the functions in terms of themselves

```
Solve[(SolveValues[{f1 == Sqrt[x + f1], f1 > 0, x > 0}, f1][[1]] // 
  Normal) == 12, x][[1]]

(* {x -> 132} *)
```

Check:

```
With[{x = 132.0`10},
 FixedPointList[Sqrt[x + #] &, 1]]

(* {1, 11.532562595, 11.980507610, 11.999187790, 11.999966158, \
11.999998590, 11.999999941, 11.999999998, 12.000000000, 12.000000000} *)
```

Next function

```
Solve[(SolveValues[{f2 == Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x - f2]],
        f2 > 0, x > 0}, f2][[1]] // Normal) == 15, x][[1]]

(* {x -> 211} *)
```

Check:

```
With[{x = 211.0`10},
 FixedPointList[Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x - #]] &, 1]]

(* {1, 15.016370292, 14.999980511, 15.000000023, 15.000000000, \
15.000000000} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

[image]

If you square this expression you get:

```
x+12 == 12^2
```

and

```
x== 12^2-12 == 132
```

Not much more complicated is:

[image]

Squaring results in :

```
x + Sqrt[x-15] == 15^2
Solve[x + Sqrt[x - 15] == 15^2, x]
```

[image]

Comment: I understand how to do it by hand, I wanted to know how to do it in MMA

Comment: The idea that after squaring the original LHS is reproduced is beyond MMA. AI has still a long way to go. And it does not hurt to think a little.